# Changing/editing street name in local OpenStreetMap server?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I followed instructions for install my own osm server on ubuntu  with osm2postgresql with carto style. It works well with Mapnik.

My area street names are wrong or missing on osm map. I found my local map from government. I want to update street names.

There are some tables, osm_planet roads, _lines, _way, _rels etc.

I am not sure Which table is exactly used in Mapnik and which coloumn should i edit for correct road name on map?

Comment: I recommend to update the street names in the OSM editor itself prior to loading the data from the OSM servers. Making local edits will not benefit the community and force someone else to update the OSM data.

Comment: ... but respect that copying street names from Google or bing maps is not wanted by the OpenStreetMap community.

Comment: If you change the OSM data, you have to share it with the community. "You are free to copy, distribute, transmit and adapt our data, as long as you credit OpenStreetMap and its contributors. If you alter or build upon our data, you may distribute the result only under the same licence. The full legal code explains your rights and responsibilities."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapnik uses planet_osm_points, planet_osm_lines, planet_osm_roads and planet_osm_polygon.

You find that information at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema and in the `<Layer>` section of the XML style files.

planet_osm_roads is used for low zoom levels only, so not for street names.

You can access the postgis database with QGIS as well, making the edit of table entries more comfortable than inside postgresql.

Comment: so the table i need to edit is osm_lines for change street names?

Comment: one more related question,  same osm_id in both osm_line and osm_roads table.  if i only update  osm_line, is it enough for see the newest name on map (mapnik tile) ? or i should update both table

Comment: As I wrote above, the roads table is only for lower zoom levels. Street names are labelled in high zoom levels, so they should not matter in the roads table. Road numbers are labelled in low zoom levels. If you need to update those, do it in both tables. Mapnik does not compare both tables, but takes the one that is specified in the rendering rules for the requested zoom level.